# Jenkins trigger parameter plugin - file parameters

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

I have Project A and downstream Project B, which takes in a file parameter.  Project B is triggered (from [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)) by A when A is completed.  Is there a way that I can predefine the file parameter (e.g. file properties file) so when project A->B, B will be able to obtain the file without needing a manual selection?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Multijob plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) for this.

A simple implementation for your example would be to have a third (multijob) project which then has two multijob phases with you one project in each one. You can specify the behaviour on the exit code for each phase and use parameters with the 'advanced' button on the configuration page

---

EDIT
The multijob plugin does not support File parameters (such as a file passed in from the browser), which is a shame

However you can fake it by

**PROJECT A (__upstream)**

where params.txt is the file parameter

[image: upstream job]

**PROJECT B (__downstream)**

where params.txt is the file parameter

[image: downstream job]

Results when triggered from A

```
Started by upstream project "__upstream" build number 8
originally caused by:
 Started by user anonymous
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building on master in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/__downstream
[__downstream] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson4094819031189787422.sh
+ touch params.txt
[EnvInject] - Injecting environment variables from a build step.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties file path 'params.txt'
[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
[__downstream] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson1756581135746292166.sh
+ cat params.txt
+ env
+ grep TEST
+ sort
TEST1=abc
TEST3=xyz
+ rm params.txt
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Results when triggered directly

```
Started by user anonymous
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building on master in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/__downstream
Copying file to params.txt
[__downstream] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson5504289990867483427.sh
+ touch params.txt
[EnvInject] - Injecting environment variables from a build step.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties file path 'params.txt'
[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
[__downstream] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson8534892071758952425.sh
+ cat params.txt
TEST1=abc
TEST3=xyz

+ env
+ sort
+ grep TEST
TEST1=abc
TEST3=xyz
+ rm params.txt
Finished: SUCCESS
```

You have to touch the file in the downstream, or else the EnvInject plugin chokes on no file and remember to remove the file (or rename) so the next run doesn't reuse the values

Comment: It doesn't seem to add additional functionality for specifically the FILE PARAMETER, though, could you please advise?

Comment: You are right for file params, however I updated my answer with a work around

Comment: Aren't the step to touch params.txt and  inject environment variables in Project B redundant? The 'use properties from file' in parameterized  trigger plugin does that for you already.